# Quiz - if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why does the **else** in the if statement still occur when an **incorrect** radio option is selected? The **else** part should only occur when no radio button is selected. The real outcome is for the next question and possible answers to appear. Heres the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/vda85aub/85/). What am I doing wrong?

```
function checkAnswer(){
submit.onclick = function(){
var radios = document.getElementsByName('choices');
var i = 0;
var len = radios.length; 

    while(i<len){
        if(radios[i].checked){
            if(radios[i].id == allQuestions[0].correctAnswer){
                userScore++;
                alert("curent score:" + userScore);
                break;
            }
        }else{
            alert("Please selected an option");
            break;
        }
        i++
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping over all radio buttons.  If there's more than 1, then it's guaranteed that at least one of them isn't selected, so you will go into the `else`.  Try this:

```
function checkAnswer(){
    submit.onclick = function(){
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('choices');
        var i = 0;
        var len = radios.length; 
        var foundSelected = false;
        while(i<len){
            if(radios[i].checked){
                foundSelected = true;
                if(radios[i].id == allQuestions[0].correctAnswer){
                    userScore++;
                    alert("curent score:" + userScore);
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++
        }
        if (!foundSelected)
            alert("Please selected an option");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `else` refers to

```
    if(radios[i].checked){
```

and is triggered whenever there is a radio button that isn't selected. This is logically different to having no radio button that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the first radio button is not selected. Then, in the first iteration of the while loop, `radios[i].checked` will be false and the loop breaks.

To check if any button is selected, you should instead do it like this:

```
function checkIfSelected() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function returns if any button is checked. Call it before you proceed.